# @XmlRootElement and <T extends Serializable> throws IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, jaxb, serializable

When I marshall an instance of this class ...

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class TestSomething<T extends Serializable> {

    T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

... the following Exception is thrown ...

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.io.Serializable is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.io.Serializable
        at public java.io.Serializable TestSomething.getId()
        at TestSomething
java.io.Serializable does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.io.Serializable
        at public java.io.Serializable TestSomething.getId()
        at TestSomething
```

How can I avoid this (without changing the type parameter to something like `<T>`)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of @XmlElement and @XmlSchemaType:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;

@XmlRootElement 
public class TestSomething<T extends Serializable> { 

    T id; 

    @XmlElement(type=Object.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="anySimpleType")
    public T getId() { 
        return id; 
    } 

    public void setId(T id) { 
        this.id = id; 
    } 
}
```

If you run the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestSomething.class);

        TestSomething<Integer> foo = new TestSomething<Integer>();
        foo.setId(4);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }
}
```

You will get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testSomething>
    <id xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">4</id>
</testSomething>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the `id` field into an attribute rather than a separate element? I'm trying to serialize an object similar to the OP's, but JAXB really doesn't like when I try to use `@XmlAttribute`. If needed I'll just open a new question.

Comment: @Matt Ball - The above scenario will work with @XmlAttribute if you use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php.  With the Metro JAXB Implementation I get an exception.

Comment: I did try switching from Metro to MOXy. If `<T extends Serializable>` then I get the same errors as the OP, along with _"@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML"_. If it's just `<T>` then I get an NPE deep down in the bowels of JAXB (stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/952370)). The same NPE occurs with Metro. Any ideas?

Comment: In the interest of not hijacking this question, I posted [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862677/). I'd be much obliged if you could take a look at some point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html) is a guide how to use interfaces with JAXB.

JAXB needs concrete classes, because it has to instantiate them when marshalling from XML. And if `T` is no concrete class, it can't be instantiated.

Comment: I already found this guide, but it doesn't help me much. When I put @XmlAnyElement to getId() and try to marshal an instance of TestSomething<Long> I get com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.Long" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@XmlAnyElement` to the 'id' field (along with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation at class level) or adding the same for getter will resolve this. (But it makes the xml element's type `any`.)